# Sql CASE statement with SUBSTRING?

Tags: sql

Hi I have a small query below :

```
SELECT  SubscriberDataId,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData,  5,  9) SubscriberCode,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData, 14, 35) SubscriberLastName,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData, 50, 15) SubscriberFirstName
FROM    Facets.FacetsImport
WHERE   DataIndicator = 'DEM1'
```

i am trying to use Case statement in this query but dont know how. what i have to do is i have to find the invalid records from the 3 fields above. so i am gonna use 
`LEN(SubscriberCode) > 9` (9 is lenght of data type) and when its greater than 9 then insert it into error table. same way for other two columns having lenght 35 and 15.

Thanks

Comment: Is this from an import of fixed-width data?

Comment: Surely all you can do here is check the length of `FacetsData` or is it delimited in some way?

Comment: Since you are using `SUBSTRING` to pass the length of your columns, you can't have `LEN(SubscriberCode) > 9`, you are using a 9 as the length of the `SUBSTRING`

Comment: this is from an import. the Field FacetsData has all the records for all the columns in work table. i have a work table created with these 3 columns with data type 9,35 and 15. Data indicator has the table names.

Comment: If the source fields have variable length, you should not be using `SUBSTRING` with fixed lengths in the first place (you'll need to use some kind of separator in that case). OTOH, if they have constant length, there is no need for any kind of length validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings will have the correct lengths if and only if the input string is `64` characters or longer:

```
INSERT
INTO    main_table
SELECT  SubscriberDataId,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData,  5,  9) SubscriberCode,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData, 14, 35) SubscriberLastName,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData, 50, 15) SubscriberFirstName
FROM    Facets.FacetsImport
WHERE   DataIndicator = 'DEM1'
        AND LEN(FacetsData) >= 64

INSERT
INTO    error_table
SELECT  SubscriberDataId,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData,  5,  9) SubscriberCode,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData, 14, 35) SubscriberLastName,
        SUBSTRING(FacetsData, 50, 15) SubscriberFirstName
FROM    Facets.FacetsImport
WHERE   DataIndicator = 'DEM1'
        AND (LEN(FacetsData) < 64 OR FacetsData IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Quassnoi, thanks for ur responce i have to apply validation individually on each of the 3 column. from ur query if the size of the field FacetsData is less than 65 then it would insert the whole record. do i have to apply validation on the main_table then? bcz there i would have records for each of the 3 fields.

Comment: @Programmer: if your string is `64` or longer, then all three records will have correct lengths. If it's shorter, then `SUBSTRING(50, 15)` will be shorter than `15` characters (which is an error), etc. If you are only validating the lengths, it will be enough. If the length is less than `64` chars, it will insert the record into `error_table` (since you didn't provide its details I omit the actual field list).

Comment: Hi Quassnoi, i talked to my teamleader about it and he said, as i am using sbstring and not converting any field and loading work table with the same data. i dotn have to apply validation on import table.i have to apply it on work table. But i really appreciate ur help. i will mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to test for >9, >35, >15 with substring because substring will give you up to the number of bytes requested. You would be better served to check the inputs outside of the database or see if there is an import tool for your DB that will do these types of checks for you.